# How to make equal space b/w UIFields using auto-layouts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am a beginner with iOS auto-layouts and I am adding five labels on my view controller and so for every thing is OK. (Here five labels width and heights are constant.)

My main requirement is how to make equal horizontal spacing b/w that five labels. I can set middle label and left and right corner labels and they are perfect. But I don't understand how to add second left and second right labels, and how to make equal space B/W them, as like another labels?

My requirement is exact like below image, please help me.

My code:

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()
{
    UILabel * left1;
    UILabel * left2;
    UILabel * middle;
    UILabel * right1;
    UILabel * right2;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    left1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    left1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    left1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:left1];

    left2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    left2.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    left2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:left2];

    middle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    middle.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    middle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:middle];

    right1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    right1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    right1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:right1];

    right2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    right2.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    right2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:right2];


    //Applying autolayouts for middle lable

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:middle
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:self.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:100]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:middle
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:self.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:10]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:middle
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:nil
                                                            attribute:0
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:50]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:middle
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:nil
                                                            attribute:0
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:20]];

    //Appying autolayouts for left1 labe1

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:left1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:100]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:left1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:10]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:left1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:0
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:50]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:left1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:0
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:20]];

    //Appying autolayouts for right1 labe1

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:right1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:100]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:right1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:-10]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:right1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:0
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:50]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:right1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:0
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:20]];


}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: I think what you want can be found using Google: [http://effortlesscode.com/evenly-spacing-views-auto-layout/](http://effortlesscode.com/evenly-spacing-views-auto-layout/)

Comment: explain me through code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is steps for you (via IB)

1. Create your 5 labels

[image]

2. Setup left and right label constraints (for left - leading, top, width, height; for right - trailing, top, width height)

[image]

3. Center horisontally middle label (top constraint, width, height, center horisontally)

[image]

4. Here is some trick - add two container views between left and middle label + middle label and right label

[image]

5. setup constraints for this containers ( leading and trailing constraints + top + height) This containers will be flexible depend on screen size

[image]

after adding constraints it should looks like

[image]

6. The last step - place other labels into green container and setup constraints as for middle label ( it should be centered in container + add top , width , height constraint )

All constraints provided at the left size, so you can easily recreate it via code, if you need

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

So I know your question was answered, but in iOS9 there are UIStackViews which are *specifically built* for this situation. Here's how to use them for future reference:

1. Shift + click and drag to select all your labels (note you don't have to size them)
   [image]
2. Click the StackView button on the bottom right of the screen
   [image]
3. Then select your StackView and set Alignment to "Fill", and Distribution to "Equal Spacing"
   [image]
   [image]
4. Then with your stackview still selected click the pin icon, and put 200 at the top, 10 and 10 for the sides, and 130 for the height. Then click add 4 constraints.
   [image]
5. Finally click the triangle icon and select update frames.
   [image]

Voila! You have your layout without having to use spacers!

Comment: unfortunately we still need to support older version :) good solution